# windows 8 glass effect

Tags: windows, dwm

I am asking how to make a glass effect for winform in windows 8.

I just saw some methods which call the DWM to make this before windows 8. But it seems DWM was no longer valid in windows 8. So is there any other methods to make glass effect winform in windows 8?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Windows 8 does not provide support for the glass effect of Vista/7. If you want to make your windows display with glass effect, you need to code it yourself, or use one of the 3rd party solutions that do so.

Comment: Thanks. Would you like to give me some 3rd party solution suggestions?

Comment: Well, on Stack Overflow, questions that ask for library suggestions are deemed off topic. But you could look here: http://superuser.com/questions/489853/aero-glass-transparent-window-borders-in-windows-8. And some websearch will yield what's available.

Comment: Thank you very much. And is there a way to make a areo glass style form without using DWM or other windows API?

Comment: You cannot do anything without ultimately driving the Windows API. But in any case, glass can only be done properly by the DWM component. It requires knowledge of the entire composition process. You can't do it for your window in isolation.

Comment: I see. If I just need some blur and transparent effect, can I make this. Maybe I just want to make a blur and transparent windows form application.